# Setting an Excel object to variable type (object) in C# Variable not showing excel methods

Tags: c#, excel

Created a class to manage validation of and excel workbook. I'm splitting the different validation steps into different methods. To facilitate this i've made a property for each of the parts of Excel and set the type as object. However my properties are retaining the Excel specific methods when called in my other methods. For example xlapp.workbooks (workboks is an unknown mber)

```
    /// <remarks>Holds the Application instance</remarks>
    public object xlApp
    {
        get
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }

    /// <remarks>Holds the value of the workbook</remarks>
    public object xlWorkBook
    {
        get
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }

    /// <remarks>Holds object for worksheet</remarks>
    public object xlWorkSheet
    {
        get
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     Excel.Application xlApp;
     Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
     Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;



    }

    /// <remarks>Opens Excel Workbook</remarks>
    public void Open_Book()
    {
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("csharp.net-informations.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").Value2.ToString());

        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on your question. Are you saying you can't access object (i.e. `Excel.Application`) specific methods when you cast it to `object`?

Comment: Correct. I was able to find the solution by adding. 'Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;' in the method Open_book